# Dereferencing iterator-value type of iterator

Tags: c++, stl

If I want to iterate through stl map, normally I use

```
for (it=my_map.begin();it!=my_map.end();it++)
{
}
```

I know that if `(typeid(map<int,char>::iterator::value_type) == typeid(pair<const int,char>))` is TRUE i.e.
value type of the `iterator` of `std::map(key_type,value_type)` is `std::pair(const key_type,value_type)`.

But if I want to do

```
std::pair<const key_type,value_type> b=it;
```

compiler will give error?

This assignment `std::pair<const key_type,value_type> b=*it;` works.

My question: What is the type of the `iterator pointer to pair` or `pair`?

Comment: It's an iterator over pairs. The iterator class in question overloads the -> and * operators to give it semantics similar to "pointer to pair", but that's not what it really is.

Comment: you can use the auto keyword too http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Comment: @Bruno The OP could indeed use `auto`, though they would still need to dereference the iterator to use it since an iterator is just a container around the pair, in this case.

Comment: Your title doesn't really describe the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterators are iterators. They are neither pointers, nor pairs. They are iterators.

"Dereferencing"<sup>1</sup> an iterator from a `std::map<K, V>` will give you a `std::pair<const K, V>&`<sup>2</sup>, yes, but the iterator itself has its own type.

---

<sub><sup>1)</sup> The `*` and `->` operators are overloaded to perform this indirection since, again, an iterator is not actually a pointer in the C++ sense.</sub>

<sub><sup>2)</sup> Or a `const std::pair<const K, V>&`, if you started off with a `std::map<K, V>::const_iterator`.</sub>

Comment: Someone's going to point out in comments that vector iterators are often implemented as pointers. They're _still_ "just iterators", though!

Comment: In some early implementations, vector iterators were often just a typedef to a pointer, but I don't know of any current implementation that does this.  (Of course, I don't have access to many different implementations at present.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah but in terms of the standard that _still_ doesn't make an iterator "be" a pointer ;)

Comment: Yes and no.  It's a typedef, so you haven't actually introduced a new type into the code.  The guarantee you get from e.g. `std::vector<>::iterator` is that it will meet the contract of a random access iterator, neither more nor less.  But if it is a typedef to a pointer, things like `typeid(std::vector<T>::iterator)` will still say it's a pointer, and `v.begin()++` won't compile.  (The latter is an interesting case: `v.begin()++` isn't part of the contract of a random access iterator, even if it works on most modern implementations.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: |<------ The standard is over here. The implementation is over here: ------->|

Comment: The standard doesn't make an iterator be a pointer, but a pointer into an array is an iterator; it fulfills the contract for a random access iterator, and anything which fulfills the contract is an iterator.  (And it''s curious that we don't hear more about contracts recently.  They're a proven technique to help write good software.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: (Because IME most people don't understand them. They prefer to obsess over facts about implementations, rather than work to the contract of an abstraction. It's kinda sad -.-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question depends on how the iterator is implemented. As long as the type supports the operations required to be an iterator, the implementation is not something you should be concerned about. In the case of `std::map`'s iterators, chances are very good that they're in fact structs, not simply pointers. The reason is that typically maps are implemented as balanced trees, and so the iterators would need to know how to traverse the tree in-order. This requires a bit of book-keeping (parent nodes, maybe?)